# Filtering a table in rails according to a particular column values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Cars Model in my rails app which has three columns Car_id , car_name and fuel_type. So in my table the car_name is coming many times.

I want to know how can I filter this Car table so that one car_name appears only one time in the returned array?

I want the full filtered table to be returned not just the distinct car names.

Comment: What do you mean by `car_name` is coming many times?

Comment: I mean the name of car like Hyundai I10  is coming in many rows.  And I want to filter the table so that this name comes only single time in the returned table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

`Car.group(:car_name).all`

Comment: This function is working fine in development (sqlite database) but giving an error in Postgres database

Comment: This code is working fine in sqlite database but in giving error in postgres database. This is the error I am getting
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "cars.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use this:

```
cars = Cars.all.uniq {|c| c.car_name}
```

This will get filtered array of Cars by `car_name` attribute.

Comment: no this is not doing the filtering, it is selecting unique rows based on car_id, which is the primary key of the table, hence it is returning the complete table back. I want uniq function to work on car_name column not on car_id column

Comment: There is `car_name` in my answer. O_O.

Comment: I dont know why but this isn't working. If I use Car.select(:car_name).distinct function then I am able to get all the unique names, but I need the complete row not just the single car_name